# Create standalone environment for Python

Tags: python, pipenv, python-standalone

I'm developing a tool based on Python, and I need to distribute this tool for users without technical skills. My way to distribute the tool was to create an installer with all the requirements, including the python executable and the libraries.

For this purpose, I tried to make a virtual environment (used pipenv to create it) and copied the resultant work directory with my code. In some cases the installer worked because some user has Python on it's machine; for user without Python some dependencies are required, but the dependencies are from a full python installation.

I already tried to use Cx_freeze, but it doesn't work for my application. Is there a way to make a standalone python environment to distribute with my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was install a version of python and the needed packages. My solution structure was:

```
-> Python
-> Program
-> run.bat
```

The first **Python**, directory is the python environment with all executables and packages. The directory **Program** contain the project files and the **run.bat** that set the environment to work with this local installation. Inside of directory `Python\Scripts` there is an archive to activate the environment. My scripts code are:

**run.bat**

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
call %~dp0Python\Scripts\activate.bat
ECHO Starting Program....
%~dp0Python\python %~dp0ProgramData\starter.py
```

**activate.bat**

```
@echo off

set "VIRTUAL_ENV=%~dp0\Python"

if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT (
    set "PROMPT=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT%"
) else (
    if not defined PROMPT (
        set "PROMPT=$P$G"
    )
    if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
        set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
    )
)
if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
    set "PROMPT=(64bits) %PROMPT%"
)

REM Don't use () to avoid problems with them in %PATH%
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME goto ENDIFVHOME
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%"
:ENDIFVHOME

set PYTHONHOME=

REM if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH (
if not defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH1
    set "PATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH1
REM ) else (
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH2
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=%PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH2

set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%;%PATH%"
```

This solution works for in my both application (64 bits and 32 bits) installation.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.pyinstaller.org/ looks like what you want, it will generate a .exe/binary of your python program that can be run on another machine. But it seems like this project is not fully supported (only supports python up to 3.6 while 3.7 is currently live) so you may need to look elsewhere if it doesn't have all features you need.

Comment: I will try to use it, but my last experiences was bad.